# Double declaration error while using profile/role DP

Tags: puppet

I'm new to puppet and i have some errors while trying to do some trivial stuff.

I keep getting a *double declaration error* but I can't figure out why.
I think that I'm missing something here, all opinions are welcome.

Puppet version : **3.7.5**
(I'm trying to use the profile/role design pattern)

Here are my files :

`tomcat.pp` (it's in ...`puppet/manifests/profile/manifests/tomcat.pp`)

```
class profile::tomcat(
    $java_version,
    $java_package,
    $version,
    $home,
    $instance,
    $user,
    $group,
    $java_opts,
    $java_home,
    $server_port = "XXXX",
    $http_port = "XXXX",
    $ajp_port = "XXXX",
) {

    class { 'java':
        version => $java_version,
        package => $java_package,
    }
    ## do stuffs
}
```

`applicationserver.pp` (it's in ...`puppet/manifests/role/manifests/applicationserver.pp`)

```
class role::applicationserver { 

  include profile::tomcatpackage

}
```

`main.pp` (I run the puppet apply with this file)

```
node tomcatvm{
    include role::applicationserver
    }
```

and finaly my `hiera` file:

```
profile::tomcat::java_version: '1.7.0_75-fcs'
profile::tomcat::java_package: 'jdk'
profile::tomcat::version: '7.0.57'
profile::tomcat::instance: 'ulg'
profile::tomcat::home: '/appli/tomcat'
profile::tomcat::user: 'tomcat-ulg'
profile::tomcat::group: 'tomcat-ulg'
profile::tomcat::java_opts: 'options'
profile::tomcat::java_home: '/usr/java/default'
```

the error I get :

```
Error: Duplicate declaration: Class[Profile::Tomcat] is already declared; cannot redeclare at /etc/puppet/modules/profile/manifests/tomcat.pp:39 on node tomcatvm.home
Error: Duplicate declaration: Class[Profile::Tomcat] is already declared; cannot redeclare at /etc/puppet/modules/profile/manifests/tomcat.pp:39 on node tomcatvm.home
```

Isn't it weird that I get 2 times the same error?
Anyway, all answers or opinions regarding my work are welcome,

Sorry for my bad english, and thanks

Comment: What you have in line 39 in file tomcat.pp:39? Because it seems that you have declared `class[Profile::Tomcat]` there, and then you declare it once again somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i had:  class { 'tomcat':
      catalina_home => $catalina_base,
      user => $user,
      group => $group,
     }. I solved my problem by renaming  'profile::tomcat' to ' profile::tomcatpackage' . do you know why it did solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as you worked around the problem by renaming your profile class, you most likely had a scope clash, i.e.

```
class profile::tomcat {
    include tomcat
}
```

is supposed to include the `tomcat` module. But when used in the scope of the `profile` module, it will resolve `tomcat` to `profile::tomcat` instead.

The proper solution is to avoid this implicit scoping.

```
class profile::tomcat {
    include ::tomcat
}
```

Using `::tomcat` makes it clear to Puppet that you are referring to the `tomcat` module and not a local class of the same name.

Comment: i get it. and since i renamed it, it was first looking profile::tomcat, but since it doesn't exists (anymore), it resolved tomcat (::tomcat). is that it?